# Selenium RC -htmlsuite error

Tags: html, selenium

after running the command `java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "iexplore" "http://www.google.com/" "C:\Selenium\suite.html" "C:\Selenium\results.html"` browser opens and shows page cannot be displayed on the test suite column.Help me out in this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally when that happens it is because the path to the Selenium Test Suite is wrong. have you made sure that it is loading the correct version?

I also noticed that you are loading the browser without the * in the browser name. E.g use

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlsuite *iexplore http://www.google.com c:\selenium\suite.html C:\selenium\results.html
```

I have a tutorial on how to get this going on my site at http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/seleniumtraining/selenium_rc_setup.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try below command and let us know your feedback, it should work.

java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "iexplore" "http://www.google.com/"  "C:\Selenium\suite.html" "C:\Selenium\results.html" -port 4444